# Are questions related to fixing or troubleshooting appliances off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I had posted [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/93522/saeco-minuto-showing-empty-water-error) about fixing a problem with my coffee machine, but before doing so, had at first dismissed Home Improvement as the Stack Exchange site for posting such a question.

In fact, I had [proposed a new one, dedicated to appliances](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/100851/appliances).

What is the concensus on appliances?

Comment: [See also](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/407/33)

Comment: The [Help center](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), says "*Installation, maintenance, and repair of major appliances.*".

Comment: Let's take this discussion to [the duplicate question](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/407/33).